# R Boxplot (and violin) look really weird when inputting different data

Tags: boxplot

I made a boxplot with a set of data (ttl) separated by sex_cd and it came out fine

[image]

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = factor(sex_cd),y = ttl, fill = factor(sex_cd))) + geom_boxplot()
```

But when I try to use another y with the same parameter, it messes up

[image]

```
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x = factor(sex_cd), y = ind_mean, fill = factor(sex_cd))) + 
geom_boxplot()
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to replicate your example without looking into data. I suggest you look into the data set closely. Below, I am pasting an example code based on the airquality dataset, hope this helps.

```
library(ggplot2)
data()
data("airquality")
head(airquality)
ggplot(data=airquality, aes(x=as.factor(Day), y=Temp, fill = as.factor(Day))) +
  geom_boxplot()
ggplot(data=airquality, aes(x=as.factor(Day), y=Solar.R, fill = as.factor(Day))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```